# Start Service on Boot Completed not working on 5.1 Lollipop

Tags: java, android, performance, broadcastreceiver, android-5.1.1-lollipop

My Bootup receiver is not working on Lollipop 5.1. I even displayed a Toast, write a file to ensure if I am getting the bootup trigger but none of it worked. 
However, my application runs properly on 5.0 and below. Haven't tried it yet on Marshmallow.

My Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver
            android:name=".BootUp"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

BootUp Receiver

```
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    public void run() {
                         while (status==0){
                            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

                            if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                                  intent = new Intent(context, PushService.class);
                                    context.startService(intent);
                            }
                               status=1;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                });
            }};
            t.schedule(mTimerTask, 1000, 1000);
```